# how to use a filter dataset to update rows dynamically in a pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm just starting to learn python and am trying to access elements in an embedded dictionary within a panda series object, that I believe I should convert to a dataframe object.

my goal is to create a new column in my master dataframe, but the values that will be updated are dynamically found starting with the current row in the master dataframe and then looking backwards until a certain condition is met.

I created a filter_significant function

```
filter = data.apply(filter_significant, axis=1, args=(df,))
```

that is currently returning a `"type:  class pandas.core.series.Series"` that contains a matching "Date" index with my master data frame to determine the rows in my master data frame that need to be updated.   The filter data looks like this:

```
| Date     | ""
|:---------|:-------------:|
|2022-09-26 |   {'High': 3}|
|2022-09-27 |   {'Low': 5} |
|2022-09-28 |   {'None': 0}|
|2022-09-29 |   {'High': 1}|
```

I realize that the filter table contains a Date index with an embedded dictionary. So how do I turn the data above into a data frame with the columns: (Index:Date, Value Type, Row Location)?

I now want to take the information in the data above to create a new column, "significant" in my master data frame, updating the value X rows above the current index with the value of 1 (True would work too), where X matches the value in the dictionary embedded in the filter dataset.  Otherwise, set the significant value to 0 (or False)

| Date | Low | High | significant |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-09-19 | 382 | 388 | 0 |
| 2022-09-20 | 385 | 386 | 0 |
| 2022-09-21 | 386 | 389 | 0 |
| 2022-09-22 | 376 | 378 | 1 |
| 2022-09-23 | 370 | 371 | 1 |
| 2022-09-24 | 371 | 372 | 0 |
| 2022-09-25 | 368 | 372 | 0 |
| 2022-09-26 | 366 | 370 | 0 |
| 2022-09-27 | 368 | 370 | 0 |
| 2022-09-28 | 364 | 372 | 1 |
| 2022-09-29 | 366 | 367 | 0 |

I'm familiar with the shift function, so intuitively I should be able to do the following:
df['significant'].shift(periods=filter_df['Row Location'].  But don't think that will work, as I need to make sure I match the current row in df w/ the matching index in filter, to ensure I set the correct "Significant" row.

Answer (score 0):

do you try this?

```
import json
import numpy as np

#first let's parse the dictionary elements
to_json = json.loads(your_fiter_data.to_json(orient="records"))    
df_v1 = pd.json_normalize(to_json)
df_v1=df_v1.rename(columns={df_v1.columns[1]:'significant_referance'})

#df_v1 like this:
date        significant_referance
2022-01-01  3

#now, we merge this parsed data and your master dataframe
final=df_v1.merge(your_master_dataframe,how='left',on='date') #or inner join

#If the low or high values ​​match the values ​​in the dictionary, write 1 if they don't match write 0.

con=[(final['Low']==final['significant_referance']) | (final['High']==final['significant_referance'])]
cho=[1]
final['significant']=np.select(con, cho,0)
```